# Python UTF-16 encoding hex representation

Tags: python, string, file, utf-16, utf

I have a string in Python 2.7.2 say u"\u0638".
When I write it to file:

```
f = open("J:\\111.txt", "w+")
f.write(u"\u0638".encode('utf-16'))
f.close()
```

In hex it looks like: FF FE 38 06
When i print such a string to stdout i will see: '\xff\xfe8\x06'.

*The querstion:* **Where is \x38 in the string output to stdout?** In other words why the string output to stdout is not '\xff\xfe\x38\x06'?

If I write the string to file twice:

```
f = open("J:\\111.txt", "w+")
f.write(u"\u0638".encode('utf-16'))
f.write(u"\u0638".encode('utf-16'))
f.close()
```

The hex representation in file contains byte order mark (BOM) \xff\xfe *twice*: FF FE 38 06 FF FE 38 06

**I wonder what is the techique to avoid writting BOM in UTF-16 encoded strings?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ASCII character `8` has hex representation `0x38`. So your string:

```
\xff\xfe8\x06
```

is *four* bytes long. Separated by spaces, the bytes are:

```
\xff \xfe 8 \x06
```

Python uses the `\x` notation for bytes that do not represent printable ASCII characters.

Comment: Put another way:  `'\x38' == '8'`

Comment: The answer would have been much more obvious if the example in the original question was `u'\u063a'`.

Answer (score 3):

Encoding to "utf-16le" or "utf-16be" (little endian or big endian) should skip writing the BOM. Without the BOM, of course, the decoder needs to know which endianness to expect.

Answer (score 1):

`\xff\xfe8\x06` *does* contain `\x38`! `8` == `\x38`.

For your second question, to avoid a BOM, if you are explicit about the endianness (using `UTF-16BE` or `UTF-16LE` codecs), no BOM will be printed.

However, the right thing to do is to use a file wrapper which handles encoding and decoding for you, and use unicode in your program. In Python 3.0, the `open` builtin function can do this:

```
fp = open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-16')
fp.write(u'write one line\n')
fp.write(u'write another line\n')
fp.close()
```

In Python 2.x, use the codec wrapper:

```
fp = codecs.open(filename, 'w', 'utf-16')
fp.write(u'write one line\n')
fp.write(u'write another line\n')
fp.close()
```